# Android ListView appears empty, but contains objects

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I'm having a really odd problem with my android listview. The listview is inside of a fragment, everything's compiling and I'm no longer getting a nullpointer error, but the listview is appearing empty. Even though it's appearing empty, the log is stating that the listview has 385 objects. I can't figure out why it's empty. I do get a blue fragment, and the listview is populated. Any ideas?

How I set the adapter:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);
    initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }

    ActivePackages = getList();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);        
    LinearLayout mContainer = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, null);
    ListView activeList = (ListView) mContainer.findViewById(R.id.activelist);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ActivePackages);
    Log.i("valueof activeList",String.valueOf(activeList.getCount())); //returns 0 
    activeList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.i("valueof activeList",String.valueOf(activeList.getCount())); //returns 385. 
}
```

This is the xml for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/activelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="#0073fd">    
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do this after setting the adapter to the listView. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() have you ever tried this after setAdapter?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I modified it to look like the above, but it still doesn't show my lists.

Comment: Is the list/fragment visible?

Comment: Yes, that's why I made it blue. I can see the blue.

Comment: What method inside of the fragment does this code exist in? Can you confirm that this code actually gets called?

Comment: @Greg This code exists inside of the onCreate, and executing the Log's would confirm that it executed correct? I have no errors or warnings.  If you would like to see similar code to what I have the guide that I followed to create this is here https://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/ My code is very similar. The biggest difference is the first fragment has a ListView inside of it (as shown above) and the code to load the ListView.

Comment: I mainly ask because is it in onCreateView(). Like would it be possible to post the whole method. Sorry I don't mean to be a pain but sometimes it's difficult to see the whole picture since even though you described everything with great detail, I am not so good at keeping all such facets in my head when looking at the code.

Comment: No, I definitely appreciate the help. I can do that. I'll put it in the main post in place of the original code, just a moment.

Comment: Alright, is there anything else you'd like to look at?

Comment: I think I get it now, it looks like you have two layouts here. One that is the content view, I assume it has a fragment tag in it. And then it looks like you are loading up another layout but are you ever attaching it? You pass the viewgroup parent to the layout inflator as null, which will just create the new instance in isolation. I mean is it as simple as using the FragmentManager instead of the layout inflater?

Answer (score 1):

In Activity you have set `setContentView(R.layout.tabs_layout);` tabs_layout and after then you have inflate a layout `R.layout.tab_frag1_layout` in `LinearLayout mContainer` but you haven't added `mContainer` in `tabs_layout`.

Try to set `mContainer` in tab layout.

Comment: How would you do something like that? I apologize I'm pretty new to android.